# How i can send emails with delay of 10 sec async parallel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

> I Want To Send 4 Emails every 10 sec   async and parallel ,  this code
>
> send only the first email only and i want that after 4 emails the loop
>
> will wait 10 sec and then continue to send 4 emails again

```
 public static void SendEmailsTask(List<string> emails)
                {
                    BackgroundTaskRunner.FireAndForgetTask(async () =>
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < emails.Count; i++)
                        {
                            BL.funcs.SendEmail(emails[i]);
                            if (i%4 == 0)
                            {                              
                                    await Task.Delay(10000);    
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }            
     public static class BackgroundTaskRunner
            {
                public static void FireAndForgetTask(Action action)
                {


HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(cancellationToken =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            action();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                    });
                }       
                public static void FireAndForgetTask(Func<Task> action)
                {
```

HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async cancellationToken =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                await action();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

> ```
>        Sending Email func async parallel to works fine
> ```

```
 public static void  SendEmail(string mail)
        {
            BackgroundTaskRunner.FireAndForgetTask(async () =>
            {
            var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                 Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail", "password"),
                    Timeout = 20000
                };
                using (var message = new MailMessage("frommail", mail)
            {
                Subject = "",
                Body = "",
                IsBodyHtml = false           
            })
            {               
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);          
            }
            });
        }
```